# How to estimate $\gamma$ in the following model?

Tags: econometrics, labor-economics, identification, simultaneous-equation-model

Suppose I have the following model:

$Q=1(x'\beta+e>0)$,

$D=1(x'\alpha+\gamma Q+u>0)$

and I want to estimate $\gamma$, the error terms $e,u$ are jointly normal.

If $e$ and $u$ are correlated, can I still estimate $\gamma$ consistently by running a probit using the second equation only?

Why or why not?

If I cannot, how could I estimate  $\gamma$ in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $u$ is normally distributed conditional on $x$ and $Q$, then you could estimate through probit the second equation. Because $Q$ depends on $e$, and $e$ is correlated with $u$, this assumption likely fails (that's your point?).  Also, note that if $u \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ then probit really estimates $\frac{\gamma}{\sigma}$. (i.e., the ratio of the coefficient to the standard deviation of the error).

If the equation with $Q$ as an outcome had a right-side variable that is not in the equation with $D$ as the outcome, then that variable could serve as an instrument and you could perform IV Probit. At present, there isn't such a variable, and thus IV probit isn't an option.

Comment: Thank you so much, Michael! This is very helpful.

Comment: Could you give me some reference on the ivprobit that you mentioned?

Comment: The documentation of the Stata command describes the method: https://www.stata.com/manuals/rivprobit.pdf

Comment: Thanks, Michael!